# html5 video using data url as src in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am using a html5 video tag to display a video in iOS app. Following using some cordova plugins for video capture I have to retrieve the mp4 video from the file system using cordova file plugin. In doing so I have to retrieve it as a base64 or binary string. I attempted to assign the base64 to scope to then reference in ng-source in the video source element. The problem is that it seems that webkit view in iOS does not want to play it, I have tested it in browser and plays fine. Is there a way around this to allow webkit view to play base64? I am thinking that a work around would be to use cordova file to make a copy in the file system to the www folder and reference the file from there in ng-source, but then as I intend to http.post this to server I would need to delete after to avoid data bloat in the www directory over time. This seems like a lot of faff to just play a video. Any ideas or insights gratefully received. Thanks Ant

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that base 64 used as a `src` tag is prohibited by apple and as such is unusable. The way around this is to store on device as a file using cordova file, and if any upload is required use cordova file transfer.